# How do I make my div scale to larger than it's original size using css animation?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which needs to start as a square, 70px x 70px and scale to a larger rectangle 140px x 210px 
For some reason the div won't scale to larger than it's original size. How can i achieve this?

This is my code:

HTML:

```
   <div id="tab">
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#tab {
-webkit-animation: enlarge 5s forwards;
width: 140px;
height: 210px;
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 0px;
background-color: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes enlarge{
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1)};
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(2,4)};
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kacmuhuw/1/

EDIT:::::
CORRECT FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/kacmuhuw/6/

Comment: The fiddle seems to work for me?

Comment: sorry in my haste i didn't change the fiddle back from how i was testing it. it is supposed to start as a 70x70 square and enlarge to a 140x210 rectangle

Comment: i am wondering why it will not get bigger if it starts from one size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Keyframe syntax is not correct. It should look like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes enlarge{
    0%  { -webkit-transform: scale(0,0) }
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(3,4) }
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kacmuhuw/8/**

without the semicolon at the end of the `}`

---

With your updated jsFiddle it is even more simple:

```
@-webkit-keyframes enlarge{
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(2,4)}
}
```

**New demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kacmuhuw/9/**

Answer (score 2):

Your code works on Chrome/Webkit, not in other browser (e.g. Firefox).

You have to add prefixes to support all browsers. Also, the right proportion is width*2 and height*3:

```
#tab {
    -moz-animation: enlarge 5s forwards;
    -ms-animation: enlarge 5s forwards;
    -o-animation: enlarge 5s forwards;
    animation: enlarge 5s forwards;
    ...
}

...

@-webkit-keyframes enlarge{
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(2,3)}
}
@-ms-keyframes enlarge{
    100% {-ms-transform: scale(2,3)}
}
@-o-keyframes enlarge{
    100% {-o-transform: scale(2,3)}
}
@-moz-keyframes enlarge{
    100% {-moz-transform: scale(2,3)}
}
@keyframes enlarge{
    100% {transform: scale(2,3)}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kacmuhuw/10/

(in the fiddle it doesn't shows well 'cause the box is absolutely positioned and it's cropped: change `top` and `left` values to see it correctly)